# Laravel, Livewire and Alertify.js - event dispatch - event.detail.xyz returning undefined

Tags: laravel, events, event-listener, laravel-livewire, dispatch

My first stack overflow question.  Web development hobbyist and learner here.  Grateful for any help at all.

I'm using Laravel 10 and livewire 3 with an alertifyjs CDN link.  I have an "Add to wishlist" button on my individual product livewire view:

```
    <div class="mt-2">
         <a href="" class="btn btn1"> <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enquire</a>
         <button type="button" wire:click="addToWishList({{ $motors->id }})" class="btn btn1"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Add To Wishlist </button>
    </div>
```

I'm dispatching an event from the livewire component, as per the livewire docs.  A different message text should be dispatched, depending on if user has already added this product to user's wishlist or not.

```
public function addToWishList($motorId)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            if(Wishlist::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('motor_id', $motorId)->exists())
            {
                // session()->flash('message', 'Already added to wishlist');
                $this->dispatch('message', [
                    'text' => 'Already added to wishlist'
                ]);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Wishlist::create([
                    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'motor_id' => $motorId
                ]);
                // session()->flash('message', 'Wishlist updated successfully');
                $this->dispatch('message', [
                    'text' => 'Wishlist updated successfully'
                ]);
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
```

Then I listen for the 'message' event in my blade layout that loads with every front end page and also contains all my CSS and scripts.

```
<body>
    @livewireScripts
    {{-- jquery --}}
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery-3.7.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    {{-- bootstrap --}}
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    {{-- aleritfyjs --}}
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

    <script>
 
        window.addEventListener('message', event => {
            alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
            alertify.success('hey '+(event.detail.text)+'!');
        });

    </script>


    <div id="app">
        @include('layouts.inc.frontend.navbar')


        <main>
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>


</body>
```

Problem description:

The alertify does only appear when I hit the wishlist button.  it doesn't trigger when I load the page.  Which seems to indicate the dispatched event is being picked up.  But my event.detail.text is returning 'undefined'.  How I know that is because when I concatenate it with some plain text like 'hey '+(event.detail.text)+'!',  it displays "hey undefined !"

If anyone can work out what I'm doing wrong or what the issue is, it would be much appreciated.

I was expecting it to pick up the 'text' item in the array

```
 $this->dispatch('message', [
   'text' => 'Wishlist updated successfully'
 ]);
```

and display the message string in the alert.  The plain text that I concatenate around 'event.detail.text' displays perfectly, but for some reason event.detail.text returns undefined.

The alertify message does appear only when I click the button which runs the addToWishList() function which dispatches events.  So it does seem the event is being received, but somehow the 'text' property doesn't contain the message.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved this.  I guess the syntax with the array I was using in the livewire component was used in an older version of Livewire.

The syntax that worked in Livewire 3.0 is:

```
  if(Wishlist::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('motor_id', $motorId)->exists())
     {
        // session()->flash('message', 'Already added to wishlist');
        $this->dispatch('message', text: 'Already added to wishlist');
        return false;
     }
     else
     {
        Wishlist::create([
          'user_id' => Auth::id(),
          'motor_id' => $motorId
        ]);
        // session()->flash('message', 'Wishlist updated successfully');
        $this->dispatch('message', text: 'Wishlist updated successfully');
     }
```

Now this.event.text contains the appropriate message.